# Cassandra Encryption (TDE) is not working with DSE

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cql3

I have a 3 node cluster in cassandra. And created system key using `dsetool createsystemkey 'AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding' 128 system_key` with proper permission and ownership to /etc/ `/etc/dse/conf/`.

But when I am creating a table with encryption I am getting the following error.

> ConfigurationException: ErrorMessage code=2300 [Query invalid because
>   of configuration issue] message="Encryptor.create() threw an error:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException Failed to initialize Encryptor:
>   com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.crypto.KeyGenerationException:
>   java.io.IOException: Couldn't encrypt input"

Table schema

> CREATE TABLE test ( id text PRIMARY KEY , data text )  WITH  compression = {'sstable_compression': 'Encryptor','cipher_algorithm' : 'AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding',   'secret_key_strength' : 128,   'chunk_length_kb' : 1 };

My DSE version : 4.8.4

Comment: please add your version info.

Comment: Do you have JCE extensions installed?

Comment: That was the mistake I made. I installed JCE and it worked. You saved my day. thanks @Zanson